# Google Analytics Data Issue in Single Day in a Month

Tags: google-analytics

My Google Analytics is showing data all the days in a month apart from a single day.
Google ads click is visible on that day as Google ads is linked with GA.

Code is fine, website was also working on that day.

Comment: Which day is it?  Is it a recent day?  Google Analytics sometimes takes a few days to process everything.